# npm SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Tags: npm

I updated, or try to anyway, npm using "sudo npm update -g" and now I cannot use npm for anything. I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/adduser.js:75
        if (!error || !response || response.statusCode !== 409) {
        ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token if
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/index.js:54:49
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/index.js:52:47)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by uninstalling node from brew and reinstalling again.